# Uploading multiple properties in a node

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm trying to upload a csv file with 5 properties of data into a single node (company).

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'FILE://company1.csv' AS line
MERGE (C:Company {Company: line.Company })
ON CREATE SET
C.Partner = line.Partner
C.Product = line.Product
C.Partner_Value = line.Partner_Value
C.Partners = line.Partners
C.Customers = line.Customers
ON MATCH SET
C.Partner = line.Partner
C.Product = line.Product
C.Partner_Value = line.Partner_Value
C.Partners = line.Partners
```

I'm receiving the following error and I'm not sure why.

```
Invalid input '.': expected 'o/O', 'r/R' or 'a/A' (line 5, column 2 
(offset: 188))
"C.Product = line.Product"
^
```

Comment: you are missing commas in between the terms you are setting (e.g. `C.Partner = line.Partner, C.Product = line.Product`)

Comment: Thanks!  It worked.